# Update Cart Woocommerce (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a small problem with my auto update cart script on the Woocommerce cart page. It is just a small snippet which updates the cart when item is added (or subtracted).
It was working fine on previous theme, however I switched theme and ran in to a glitch.
Snippet just finds the "update" field which is hidden, and updates it.

Snippet is below

```
 jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
             jQuery("[name='update_cart']").closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name=\"update_cart\"]' );
                  });
                 jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
              jQuery("[name='update_cart']").closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name=\"update_cart\"]' );
                });
                  jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
               jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        });
```

The html for that field is

```
  <input type="submit" class="hidden" name="update_cart">
```

Which is right below the back to shop button near bottom

The full cart.php code is below

```
do_action('woocommerce_before_cart');
get_template_part('woocommerce/theme-custom/order', 'step');
?>
<script>
           jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
             jQuery("[name='update_cart']").closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name=\"update_cart\"]' );
                  });
                 jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
              jQuery("[name='update_cart']").closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name=\"update_cart\"]' );
                });
                  jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
               jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
        });
</script>
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" method="post" class="woocommerce-cart-form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table'); ?>
                <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="product-name" colspan="2"><?php _e('Product', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                        <th class="product-price"><?php _e('Price', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                        <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e('Quantity', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                        <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e('Total', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                        <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_cart_contents'); ?>

                    <?php
                    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
                        $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                        $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

                        if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)) {
                            $product_permalink = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink($cart_item) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                            ?>
                            <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr(apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key)); ?>">

                                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                                    <?php
                                    $thumbnail = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);

                                    if (!$product_permalink) {
                                        echo ent2ncr($thumbnail);
                                    } else {
                                        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url($product_permalink), $thumbnail);
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Product', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    if (!$product_permalink) {
                                        echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key) . '&nbsp;';
                                    } else {
                                        echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url($product_permalink), $_product->get_name()), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                                    }
                                    // Meta data
                                    echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item );

                                    // Backorder notification
                                    if ($_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder($cart_item['quantity'])) {
                                        echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__('Available on backorder', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="mobile-content">
                                       <?php
                                       echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price($_product), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                                       echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                           '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">%s</a>',
                                           esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
                                           __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
                                           esc_attr($product_id),
                                           esc_attr($_product->get_sku()),
                                           __('Remove', 'doma')
                                       ), $cart_item_key);
                                       ?>
                                   </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Price', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price($_product), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-quantity"
                                    data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Quantity', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    if ($_product->is_sold_individually()) {
                                        $product_quantity = sprintf('1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key);
                                    } else {
                                        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(array(
                                            'input_name' => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                            'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                            'max_value' => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                            'min_value' => '0',
                                        ), $_product, false);
                                    }

                                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item);
                                    ?>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Total', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal($_product, $cart_item['quantity']), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="product-remove">
                                    <?php
                                    echo apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                        '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="cs-font clever-icon-close"></i></a>',
                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
                                        esc_attr($product_id),
                                        esc_attr($_product->get_sku())
                                    ), $cart_item_key);
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    do_action('woocommerce_cart_contents');
                    ?>
                    <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_cart_contents'); ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="bottom-table-cart">
                    <a class="btn back-shop" title="<?php echo esc_attr__('Continue Shopping', 'doma') ?>"
                       href="<?php echo get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('homepage')) ?>">
                        <?php echo esc_html__('Continue Shopping', 'doma') ?>
                    </a>
                  <input type="submit" class="hidden" name="update_cart">
                    <?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_actions'); ?>
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('woocommerce-cart'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_cart_table'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 cart-collaterals">
            <?php do_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php do_action('zoo_woocommerce_cart_collaterals'); ?>
</form>
<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_cart'); ?>
```

It was working fine before, but now for some reason only updates every SECOND increment, ie the first increment it does nothing, then on the next one it updates and this is repeated for subsequent attempts with exactly the same behaviour ie miss one, update next etc. The same happens on subtraction.

So a little puzzled as to why its not working properly now.

Any tips welcome

Thanks

Comment: You should add in your question all related code and you should better explain what your code should do… Remember: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: Hi,that IS all the jQuery code,the desired behaviour is to update on every increment/decrement, and it was working fine before. Now it only updates on every 2nd increment/decrement, completely ignoring the 1st increment every time. I have added the cart.php code now to see if that helps anything. Thanks

Comment: Normally Woocommerce does that alone by default, without any need of additional jQuery code… By default there is: `<input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update cart">` and Woocommerce activate the button each time you change quantities in cart page… so when you click this button everything is updated without any additional needs.

Comment: Hi, no that is not the case or I would not have added the code, other theme had to have this added to update cart, and I just transferred it to new theme. WC does not auto update cart by default, hence the addition.

Comment: IE WC does not activate the button, user has to hit the button, hence the code to do it on auto.

Comment: Surely the problem can comes from your themes folder "woocommerce" where customized templates are located… They are surely outdated (you can check that going in **Woocommerce** > **Status** at the end of the page "template overrides" (warnings in red))…

Comment: Lot of overides but none outdated, its latest WC 3.4

Comment: There is the problem… So you should contact themes authors support threads to get latest Woocommerce updates, or hire a real Woocommerce developer…

Comment: Hi, theme authors are real Woocommerce developers! seems to be simple problem where only updates every alternate click? WC files are latest versions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the update cart button on change of quantity by clicking on input or by inserting direct into field so just need to paste this code into functions.php and you are good to go. This code is tested and worked great.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_update_qty' ); 
 
function refresh_update_qty() {
   if (is_cart()) {
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.quantity input.button, input.qty', function(){
  
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
         });
      </script>
      <?php
   }
}
```